# Encoding problem with Polish letters in GeoPandas

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas, encoding, poland

I have the problem with encoding because I need Polish letters and `encoding="utf-8"` didn't work.

```
import geopandas

df = geopandas.read_file(r'/home/gis/adresypolska/PRG_PunktyAdresowe_POLSKA.shp', layer ='PRG_PunktyAdresowe_POLSKA', encoding = "utf-8")
```

I got this, look at second and third column:

How can I solve that?

[image]

Comment: Please, don't use an image, use text. The problem is  the original encoding of the dbf file which is not  "utf-8"

Comment: How can I solve that?

Comment: Either converting the original data into UTF-8 or trying some other encodings in GeoPandas, e.g. [ISO-8859-2](https://www.terena.org/activities/multiling/ml-docs/iso-8859.html#ISO-8859-2) or [Windows-1252](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
encoding = "cp1250"
```